# Building a simple Group Chat View in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I'm building a very simple online chat room App. What I have achieved is something like below right now:

```
Robert:blah..
Tom: yes blah..
David(You): That sounds cool!
Lily: Do you know blah...
Robert:blah..
Robert:blah..
David(You): Wow! Blah...
```

The new feature/problem I'm facing is that I want current user's talks to show on the right. 
Like below(this is what David see on his screen):

```
Robert:blah..
Tom: yes blah..
                                  That sounds cool! : David(You)
Lily: Do you know blah...
Robert:blah..
Robert:blah..
                                       Wow! Blah... : David(You)
```

Each line above is a TextView, and I'm dynamically creating TextView whenever there's new message, then adding them to the `LinearLayout` that contains these TextView. In order to make David(current user)'s talk on the right, I tried to set align right and I change the `LinearLayout` to `RelativeLayout`. But then I realize once I use `RelativeLayout`, all talks are in the same line overlapping each other since I didn't set their height.. Can anyone shed some light on how to achieve this please? My codes below:

```
...    
//new messages are stored in lines[]
for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {

    TextView newLine = new TextView(getBaseContext());

    newLine.setText(lines[i]);

    // check if the speaker of this line is user himself            
    if (speakerName.equals(userName)) {

    //change the layout of this textView to make it align right..

    }
    myLinearView.addView(newLine);//add to linearView that contains these talks 
}
```

Comment: you should consider using listview, appending textview this way would consume massive amount of memory after time.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely need to use a ListView, as Chor WaiChun mentioned.  However, the way you would do this with a relative layout would be to set the RelativeLayout.layoutParams for the view with a rule that sets it to layout_below the previous view.  Just like you would in XML.

Also, even if you insist on adding 1 view per line (which as previously stated is wrong, use a ListView), there's no reason not to use the LinearLayout.  You can have a LinearLayout with right justified text, just set the gravity to right.